# how to set casbin conf if I want to use rabc with resource roles at the same time match the restful api

Tags: casbin

I use the casbin with rabc with resource model, this is my conf:

```
[request_definition]
r = sub, obj, act

[policy_definition]
p = sub, obj, act

[role_definition]
g = _, _
g2 = _, _

[policy_effect]
e = some(where (p.eft == allow))

[matchers]
m = g(r.sub, p.sub) && g2(r.obj, p.obj) &&（r.act == p.act
```

this is the policy:

```
p, data_group_admin, data_group, write

g, alice, data_group_admin
g2, /api/:id, data_group
```

this is the request:

```
alice, /api/1, read
alice, /api/2, write
```

the result is **false, false**
actually, I expect the result is **true, true**,I want to the resource can support restful format, how to set the conf?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AddMatchingFunc` to make the default role manager knows how to spread the role link because by default it compares role name exactly.

the example code may look like

```golang
e.GetRoleManager().(*defaultrolemanager.RoleManager).AddMatchingFunc('matcher', util.KeyMatch)
```

for more information you can see https://github.com/casbin/casbin/blob/master/rbac/default-role-manager/role_manager.go#L163

updated, add sample code

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/casbin/casbin/v2"
    defaultrolemanager "github.com/casbin/casbin/v2/rbac/default-role-manager"
    "github.com/casbin/casbin/v2/util"
)

func main() {
    e, _ := casbin.NewEnforcer("./model.conf", "./policy.csv")

    e.GetRoleManager().(*defaultrolemanager.RoleManager).AddMatchingFunc("key_match", util.KeyMatch2)
    res1, _ := e.Enforce("alice", "/api/1", "write") // true
    res2, _ := e.Enforce("alice", "/api/2", "read")  // false
}
```

This will result true, because alice belongs to data_group_admin and /api/1 belongs to data_group, data_group_admin can write data_group

Since you didn't define the read policy, so the second enforce will return false.

Comment: It seems not effect with rbac with resource model:
```
    m.AddDef("r", "r", "sub, obj, act") // role
    m.AddDef("p", "p", "sub, obj, act")
    m.AddDef("g", "g", "_, _")
 m.AddDef("g", "g2", "_, _")
 m.AddDef("e", "e", "some(where (p.eft == allow))")
 m.AddDef("m", "m", `g(r.sub, p.sub)&& g2(r.obj, p.obj) &&  r.act == p.act `)
 rm := defaultrolemanager.NewRoleManager(10)
 rm.(*defaultrolemanager.RoleManager).AddMatchingFunc("matcher", util.KeyMatch2)
 rm.(*defaultrolemanager.RoleManager).AddDomainMatchingFunc("matcher", util.KeyMatch2)
```
this is the go code,  model set

Comment: @M.Mike plz make a github issue

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion.

```
g2, /api/:id, data_group
```

g2 need two sub not obj and sub.

I mean: if you want alice alice can access `/api/1`
You need :

```
p: alice, /api/1, read
p: alice, /api/2, write
```

or:

```
p: data_group_admin, /api/1, read
p: data_group_admin, /api/2, write
g: alice, data_group_admin
```

Summary: distinguish `sub` and `obj` in `r`, `p` and `g`.